# Request.Form[""] returns null in foreach loop

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, razor, foreach

In my `.cshtml` I have this:

```
 <input type="text" id="snsearch" name="snsearch" style="width:180px" />
```

In my `.cshtml.cs` I have this:

```
 var v = Request.Form["snsearch"]; //Gets the value of the textbox OK

 foreach (var x in y)

 {
   if (x.Contains(v)) //v becomes null after one iteration
   {
     //do something
   }

 }
```

I have tried setting a bool to capture the variable only once but that didn't pan out. Anyone have a suggestion or another approach at how to do this?

Comment: what is "y" ? i don't understand

Comment: An enumerable collection...tried to simply the question- it doesn't matter what I'm looping through, but after the first iteration `v` becomes null

Comment: OK "v" example do you share a real value?

Comment: var v = Request.Form["snsearch"]; example value

Comment: Are you sure that x might not me the null value? Are you receiving any errors on that line, if you are could you post them?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get value of input,you can use `BindProperty` to bind value in razor page:

cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="snsearch" name="snsearch" style="width:180px" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
public string snsearch { get; set; }
public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            foreach (var x in y)

            {
                if (x.Contains(snsearch)) 
                {

                    //do something
                }

            }
            return Page();
        }
```

result(I use fake data to test)：
[image]